# for php, is there ever a reason to use protected if your class is final?

Tags: php

An example:

```
class A {
  protected function foo() {
    echo 'fooA';
  }
}
```

I want to override foo() in my child class, which is final. Is there ever a reason to use protected here?

```
final class B extends A {
  protected function foo() {
    echo 'fooB';
  }
}
```

vs

```
final class B extends A {
  private function foo() {
    echo 'fooB';
  }
}
```

Comment: Try it both and you will find the answer!

Comment: A private method cannot be called from an extended class, but a final method can be.

Comment: @Anthony that's not the point, IMHO

Comment: You can't override a protected method in child class with `private` keyword. It **must** be public or protected.

Comment: Being able to call the method is the point, actually. You might want a method to be allowed to be called from the descendant class (like `B->foo()`) without allowing the method to be overriden, so it would need to be protected (visible and callable by extended classes) but final (can't be overriden by extended classes).

Comment: Nvm, I see what you are asking. Why mark the visibility of a method if the class itself is marked final. I think your question is easily misreadable as "why mark a method as both protected and final"

Answer (score 1):

There's no real difference. Both `private` and `protected` can only be called from within the class, and `protected` can additionally be called from sub-classes.

Since you're declaring the class as `final`, there will never be a sub-class so from a practical point of view `private` and `protected` have the same effect here.

Comment: As a note, when using magic methods in a practical way, a reflection can be called to determine the protected or private visibility of a method, and can be used to deter outside calls to private methods by only allowing calls to a reflection that 'isProtected()' in the final class.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you can't override protected method with private one. The access modifier must stay the same or be higher. So it must stay protected or can be public